# How to pass a calculated value from a child to a parent in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, components, parent-child

am am trying to pass a calculated value from a child back to the parent. The child component would use several user inputs to calculate a single value which would be passed back to the parent.

I have compiled a very simplified version below. The Parent does not need to know any of the user inputs to the child component. However, in my app I plan to have a dynamic list of the Child components and the Parent component would show the sum of all outputs from all Child components.

Parent component

```
export default function Parent() {
    //function that sums up all Child results
    const [value, setValue] = useState(1);
    const setValueFromChild = useCallback((e) => {
        var newValue = value + e;
        setValue(e)
    });

    //Included just 2 children (hard-coded) for clarity
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Total: {value}</h1>
            <Child cbfunction={setValueFromChild} />
            <Child cbfunction={setValueFromChild} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Child Component:

```
const Child = (cbfunction) => {
    //Handles change in input from the selector tag
    const [sel, setSel] = useState(1);
    const onSelectChange = (e) => {
        setSel(e)
    }

    //Handles change in input from input field
    const [inp, setInp] = useState(1);
    const onInputChange = (e) => {
        setInp(e);

    }

    //Calculates the result. In reality this would be a complex function with if statements, etc.
    const calc = (s, i) => {
        var result = Number(sel) + Number(inp);
        cbfunction(result); //*****THIS IS WHERE I'M HAVING TROUBLE
        return (result);
    }

    return (
        <div>
        <select onChange={(e) => onSelectChange(e.target.value)} value={sel}>
            <option value={1}>1</option>
            <option value={2}>2</option>
            <option value={3}>3</option>
        </select>
        <input onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e.target.value)}  value={inp}>
        </input>
        <p>{calc(sel, inp)}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I can't figure out how to call the Parent function when the state of the Child component changes. I wan't to pass the callback function down through the props to the child but it doesn't seem to work the way I'm calling it.

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: it is const `Child = ({cbfunction}) =>` no `const Child = (cbfunction) `

Answer (score 0):

it seems that your useCallback is not doing what you want because you don't pass the calculated value up

```
    const setValueFromChild = useCallback((e) => {
       //const instead of var!!!
        const newValue = value + e;
        setValue(newValue)
        // this is not what you want setValue(e)
    },[setValue]);
```

also if you don't pass an array of dependencies it will not be optimized at all, you should install ESlint in your project it would help you with what you need to include in the array but I thing you would need to pass setValue as on my example.

Also Alan Omar is correct in the comment you should destructure it from props in child component or refer to it via props.cbfunction